# Windows 8 Release Preview stopped working during installation progress at 50 - 60

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, windows-8-preview

i m currently installing (i am currently upgrading from windows 7) windows 8 release preview on my dell n411z laptop pc. But when it reach at progress of 50 -60, it stop working gives error message **installation failed**

What exactly is the problem?

How do I solve this problem?

How can i find the installation log file?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: Unless you provide more information we cannot help you.

Comment: @Ramhound Says the truth!!

Comment: there isn't much information. How can i find that?

Comment: how can i find the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing Windows 8 stores it's logs in the [same place Windows 7 does.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744583%28v=ws.10%29)

Being a Release Preview, I doubt you'll get too much support but you may want to report it to Microsoft so they can take a look.